# system("echo * > toto") returns an error

Tags: command-line, system, syntax

when I test this command : system("echo * > toto") (the file toto exists)

This error is returned : `bash: syntax error near unexpected token`"/bin/echo x"'`

and I don't understand why.
Thank you in advance for you advices.

Comment: try "echo '*' > toto" so the shell does not try to interpret the *

Comment: When you test this command where? What's the context here?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to execute the `system(...)` __C__ standard library function as a __shell__ function (instead of from inside a C program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give insight into what is happening:

```
$ echo * | tr ' ' '\n' | sort >toto_a

$ ls -d * | tr ' ' '\n' | sort >toto_b
ls: cannot access VirtualBox: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access VMs: No such file or directory

$ diff -u0 toto_a toto_b
--- toto_a  2014-06-30 18:50:41.939160184 +0200
+++ toto_b   2014-06-30 18:50:45.571160103 +0200
@@ -34,2 +33,0 @@
-VirtualBox
-VMs
```

... now this is assuming that "system()" launches a bash session for `echo * >toto`

To get more predictable results one might use `system("bash -c 'echo * > toto')` and maybe add an absolute path to `toto`.